# Lights are dark in build, but are fine in editor

Tags: unity-game-engine, lighting, light, urp

I am using URP Version 12.1.7 and Unity 2021.3.9f1.
Lights are fine in the editor, but in build it becomes too dark.

Before Unity update everything was fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a stupid bug from Unity's side. I had "Screen space ambient occlusion" feature added to my UniversalRenderPipelineAsset_Renderer. Unity was applying it even though it was disabled. I had to remove this feature from UniversalRenderPipelineAsset_Renderer to fix it.